# Crear addEventListener en un span cuyo id esta contenido en una variable

Tags: javascript, variables, eventos

buenos días.
Primero que todo pido disculpas por lo poco claro que es el titulo, no he sabido describirlo mejor. En segundo lugar aclaro que lo que voy a poner aquí es un ejemplo inventado y sencillo para que entendais cual es mi duda y evitar complicarnos innecesariamente intentando resolver mi duda en mi código.

El ejemplo es el siguiente:
En la pagina hay un input donde escribir y un botón.
Al pulsar el botón se ejecuta la siguiente función:
-Mediante un innerHTML crea un elemento html (un span) con el valor del input como id.
-Además quiero que cree un addEventListener sobre ese objeto, pero claro, el id de ese span solo lo tengo almacenado en la variable y no se como utilizar la variable para hacer referencia a cada uno de los span que se van creando.

```js
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
        var listaSpan = "";
        document.getElementById("boton").addEventListener('click', function(){

            valor = document.getElementById("cajaDeTexto").value;
            listaSpan += "<span id='"+ valor +"'>"+ valor +"</span> ";
            document.getElementById("lista").innerHTML = listaSpan;
            //hasta aquí todo bien, es justo aquí donde insertaria una linea con la que me surge la duda. Debajo del ejemplo lo explico.
        }, false);
      }, false);
```

```css
*{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
div{
         padding: 20px;
      }
span{
        background-color: #8dc3ed;
        padding: 10px;
        display: block;
        border-radius: 3px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ejemplo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <div style="background-color:#d0d0d0">
      Introducir nombre:
      <input type="text" name="" value="" id="cajaDeTexto">
      <button type="button" name="button" id="boton">Botón</button>
    </div>
    
    <div id="lista">
      <span>Aquí irán apareciendo los elementos span a medida que sean introducidos mediante la caja de texto y el botón</span>
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, si inspeciono la pagina el elemento span se ha creado correctamente en el DOM con su correspondiente id, de echo podeis verlo en el ejemplo.
Pero luego, quiero que se les añada un addEventListener a cada uno de los objetos que se vayan creando pero obviamente no puedo ponerle algo asi:

```
document.getElementById(valor).addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById(valor).style.display = "none"; //por ejemplo
}, false)
//tambien he probado: .getElementById("valor") y .getElementById("'"+valor+"'")
```

Lo que me gustaría es poder imprimir el valor de la variable valor directamente en el código js para que este lo interpretase así. No se si me explico... Quizás me estoy confundiendo, no estoy muy seguro de cual es el problema y aun menos la solución. En definitiva lo que quiero es que para cada uno de esos spans que se creen, se cree a su vez un addEventListener sobre cada uno de ellos. Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo!

---

Este es mi código en realidad:

```
var lista = document.getElementById("lista");

function listaCookies(){  //actualiza la lista de cookies

  var cookies = document.cookie.split('; ');
  var listaCookies = '';

  //bla bla bla

  for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {

    var nombre = cookies[i].substring(0, (cookies[i].indexOf('=')));
    var idEliminar = "btn_eliminar_" + nombre;

    var close = document.createElement('button');
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    close.textContent = 'x';
    close.className = "eliminar";
    span.id = nombre;
    span.textContent = cookies[i];
    span.appendChild(close);
    lista.appendChild(span);

    close.addEventListener('click', function(){
      //span.remove();
      //document.getElementById(nombre).remove();
      //close.parentNode.remove();
      //this.parentNode.remove();
      //HE PROBADO TODO ESTO PERO NADA...
    });
  }

  //bla bla bla

};
```

Comment: ¿Quieres que se cree un `span` cada vez que se pulsa el botón con el `id` de lo ingresado en la caja de texto y que el `span` tenga un listener para el evento `click`?

Comment: Exacto. La dificultad la tengo al intentar crear el listener sobre cada uno de esos spans porque no se como referirme a ellos sin que me de error.

Comment: Pues si ya estás creando un input, con id y todo, por qué no le pones un evento onlick que llame a una función ya declarada y ya está?
´"<span id='"+ valor +" onclick=mostrarValor(this)'>"+ valor +"</span> "´

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es usar la función [`Document#createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) para crear un nuevo elemento en el árbol DOM y poder asociarle un evento; también puedes poner directamente el atributo `onclick`. Por cuestiones de limpieza y de control del elemento recientemente creado prefiero la primera opción.

**Actualización**

Debido a tu comentario:

> No funciona el botón de cerrar en mi caso, pues esos valores los obtengo troceando con `.split()` una cadena de texto (document.cookie) y con un bucle for **hago que se dibujen** todos los spans correspondientes a cada uno de los elementos del array resultante.

La lógica sigue siendo la misma. El único problema que tienes en tu loop es que **siempre estás haciendo referencia a la última cookie** debido a un problema de alcance de la variable de control. La opción vieja es usar un [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) para **crear un nuevo ámbito de ejecución** donde se **mantenga la cookie actual** para poder operar con ella; la opción nueva es usar el operador `let` en lugar de `var`.

**Ejemplo**

```js
var mycookies = 'c1=Cookie1; c2=Cookie2; c3=Cookie3; c4=Cookie4';

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var listaSpan = document.getElementById('lista');
  var input = document.getElementById('cajaDeTexto');
  var btn = document.getElementById('boton');
  var cookies = mycookies.split('; ');
  
  
  for (var i=0; i<cookies.length; i++) {
    var cookie = cookies[i];
    var cookieName = cookie.substring(0, cookie.indexOf('='));
    var cookieValue = cookie.substring(cookie.indexOf('=') + 1);
    
   (function (name, value) {
     var span = document.createElement('span');
      var close = document.createElement('button');
      close.textContent = 'x';
      span.id = name;
      span.textContent = value;
      span.appendChild(close);
      close.addEventListener('click', function() {
        span.remove();
      });
      // aquí se agrega el span al árbol
      listaSpan.appendChild(span);
    })(cookieName, cookieValue);
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  padding: 20px;
}

span {
  background-color: #8dc3ed;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

span button {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  font-size: 13px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="lista">
  <span style="background-color: gold; text-align: center">
    Lista de cookies
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! Buena solucion, no conocia el metodo createElement y que luego se podian editar sus propiedades. Aunque ahora tengo otro problema ya que esto era solo un ejemplo ficticio. En mi codigo la lista esta compuesta por spans que dentro tienen un button. Ese button es el que tiene el listener y el span contiene el valor introducido. La finalidad de ese button dentro del span será eliminarlo de la lista. Con .appendChild() no puedo hacer eso...
Nota:La lista se actualiza constantemente.
Deberia quedar algo asi:
<span> valor <button class='eliminar' id='valor'>x</button></span> "

Comment: He editado mi respuesta. Como verás, se puede poner un botón dentro del span de la misma manera que añadiste el span a la lista. En el código de ejemplo que he añadido, cuando se pulsa el botón *'x'*, el span se elimina (del DOM).

Comment: Vaya, no sabes cuanto estoy aprendiendo gracias a ti! Te lo agradezco mucho! Aunque no funciona el botón de cerrar en mi caso, pues en realidad esos valores no los obtengo de un input al pulsar un botón sino que los obtengo troceando con .split() una cadena de texto (document.cookie) y con un bucle for hago que se dibujen todos los spans correspondientes a cada uno de los elementos del array resultante del split. He editado mi pregunta. Disculpa, es mi primera pregunta aqui, supongo que la proxima vez lo mas sensato será exponer mi caso real desde el principio... :S

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta. En la próxima oportunidad, coloca tu problema real, sin miedo ;).

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!! Es como una funcion anonima a la que le pasas parametros, no? Funciona aunque no comprendo todo eso. Voy a inverstigar eso del ambito de ejecucion y la variable de control, que me suena a chino. Te estoy muy agradecido por tu ayuda y por todo lo que he aprendido! :)

Comment: En efecto, es una función anónima o closure. Es grato ser de ayuda. Ante cualquier otra duda o problema, no dudes en publicar.